# Get current opportunity id in salesforce screen flow

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

I am showing a flow from the quick action from opportunity screen. I want to get the opportunity id in the flow. I tried GetRecord element but the condition only returns the top most id. I want to get the contact information from the opportunity id. Is it possible? How to show contact info in flow?

Answer (score 0):

To retrive the opportunity id you just have to create a text variable named ***recordId*** and it will be stored automatically when the flow is launched from the record as a quick action or when you expose the flow in the flexi page